# Classic Bluetooth discovery does not give me details other than MAC Address

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to integrate Bluetooth Classic discovery and create connection between phone and device,but Discovering device does not gives more details in Receiver.My Code is:

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        }else {
                mBluetoothAdapter =BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            }

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

 public static class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                LogUtils.errorLog("BC ","@@: "+gson.toJsonTree(device));
                //callback.onDeviceFound(device);
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                //  callback.onDiscoveryFinished();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should at least specify which details you want.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko as per example?
I want every field available.For example , Name , Mac Address and other data.

Answer (score 0):

The code says it has the `BluetoothDevice` instance of the device that is recently discovered. Now following the developer guide [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice) we can find out this class has many information, which can be requested using it's methods.

For example:

`device.getAddress()`, to get the machine address of the device.

`device.getName()`, to get the local name of the device.

Answer (score 0):

important thing about Bluetooth is mac address. once you get mac address,
1. you can pair, connect send and receive data

Example:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
device.getName();
mSocket.connect(createRfcomSecureConnection);
```